# How can i notify react native app for the changes, when any changes is made by user from web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

currently i am working on a project where mobile app and web app is developed for admin and user.i just want update my react native app over web admin changes .but without any app changes how can i do this.if you can help.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood your question. When a change is made by user from web app, you want to notify your react native app of that change? You want server to tell your mobile app that something has changed and provide the new data?

Comment: yes  i want to do the same task

Comment: @c0m1t any idea how can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways that your client app can be notified:

1. **Websocket:** It is a two-way interactive communication session between the user's browser and a server. So server can send messages to clients whenever they need to be notified. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)
2. **Regular polling**
   You Send a request to server periodically and asks whether you have to update anything. And server responds to your requests and closes the connection. This option is not very performant, because the rate of your data update is probably too low and you are making tons of requests even when there is no change in backend data.
3. **Long polling**: You send a request to server, but this time server does not close the connection until it has a message to send. Whenever there is a change in the backend data that your client needs to be notified, server responds to your request and closes the connection.
4. **Server-sent events**: It enables the client to receive updates from a server via an HTTP connection. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)
5. **Push notifications**

Each of these solutions have their own cons and pros which depend on your requirements.